# Xamarin MT.D attributes form double

Tags: c#, xamarin, attributes, double

So I have this form class that will display when I hit add.

```
namespace Checkbook
{
    public class AccountDialog
    {
        public AccountDialog (AccountItem account)
        {
            Name = account.Name;
            Balance = account.Balance;
        }

        [Entry("Name")]
        [Alignment(UITextAlignment.Right)]
        public string Name { set; get; }

        [Entry("Balance")]
        public double Balance { set; get; }

        [Section("")]
        [OnTap("SaveAccount")]
        [Alignment(UITextAlignment.Center)]
        public string Save;
    }
}
```

When running the application on iOS it doesn't like the `double` type. I'm not sure what else to use since float ends up as a slider and it seems no one else has used double. This is how I display the DialogViewController.

```
public void ShowAddAccountDialog(AccountItem item){
            currentItem = item;
            accountDialog = new AccountDialog (currentItem);
            context = new BindingContext(this, accountDialog, "Account Details");
            detailsScreen = new DialogViewController (context.Root, true);
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController (detailsScreen, true);
        }
```

any thoughts on how I can get a decimal field for a user to enter a balance?

Comment: what do you mean by ' it doesnt like the double type'? Also have you tried using the `decimal` type instead of `double`?